# Why I had to re-save permalink setting after moving my WordPress site to another hosting provider?

Tags: permalinks

I just move WP site from Namecheap to Inmotion Hosting.

Today when I checking it return 404 (Not WP Theme 404, I mean basic 404 error) for all pages excluding home page.

I  re-save permalink and now works fine.

Why it happens and what is the solution for it?

Comment: are you planning on switching host multiple times? else i would suggest to just forget about it and regenerate your permalinks.

Comment: @Stender I just want to make not it happen future when site moving hosting to another one. Because I usually move 5-6 sites per year...

Comment: Are you sure your .htaccess was transfered in the move? It will be regenerated when you save permalinks.

Comment: @janh Yes, I am sure that  .htaccess was moved because I just checked the zip file which I uploaded....

Comment: Can you reproduce the problem?